# Camera " Retake " and " Use photo " buttons not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera

Library link : https://github.com/yackle/CLImageEditor

Using camera take a photo and use photo to editing using `CLImageEditor`  custom library. After open image in library back to camera view `Retake` and `Use photo` buttons not working.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    imageInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:info];
    UIImage *a_img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
CLImageEditor *editor = [[CLImageEditor alloc] initWithImage:a_img];
editor.delegate = self;
   [picker pushViewController:editor animated:YES];
}
```

**STEPS:**

1. Click on camera button to update profile picture.
2. Take a photo and click on `Use photo` button, on this click above method is calling and push `CLImageEditor` controller to modification of image.
3. Without modification click on back button (It's pop to camera view).
4. Now on click `Retake` or `Use photo` buttons to take new photo or editing existing photo again `Not working`

Comment: what you meant `not working`?

Comment: Report an issue: https://github.com/yackle/CLImageEditor/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue

Comment: use this : IQMediaPickerController

Answer (score 0):

**Library link : https://github.com/yackle/CLImageEditor**

**in this imagepicker did cancel method right**

```
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker:
    UIImagePickerController) {
                let editor = CLImageEditor()
                editor.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            
        }
```